# Не работает сравнение строк

Tags: javascript

Привет

Кусок Html:

```
<a class="class_link" href="">хатха-йога</a>
```

Кусок js:

```
if ($('.class_link').text() == "хатха-йога"){
    alert("good");
}
```

Почему не выводит alert?

После 9-го комментария: выложил полный скрипт: http://jsfiddle.net/eCdLt/3/
если закооментирую также у себя - условие не работает, отключил все скрипты, кроме своего и jquery.

Ничего не пойму

upd
Нашёл, в чём дело. Проблема с кодировкой. В случае английских букв работает. Спасибо, ребята. Пока пауза

upd  Не работает на живом сайте 
console.log("хатха-йога");
console.log($('.class_link').text()); - в обоих случаях выводится "хатха-йога".
Посмотрите сайт: yogaclass.pro

Скрипт: http://yogaclass.pro/assets/templates/yogaclass/js/script.js

Строки

```
            console.log($('.class_link').text());
            console.log("хатха-йога");

            if ($('.class_link').text() == "хатха-йога"){
                alert("good in case of using jQuery");
            }

            var a = "хатха-йога";
            if (a == "хатха-йога"){
                alert("good in case of using definite variable");
            }
```

UPD
Поправил кодировку скрипта, а также кодировку jQuery. В случае введения переменной а работает, если текст берёт скрипт - не работает

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eCdLt/ — работает же

Comment: обверните скрипт в код $(document).ready(function(){})

проблема скорее всего именно в этом

Comment: не понимаю, почему не происходит сравнения. Вот это показывает: alert($('.class_link').text());

Comment: скрипт обёрнут:$(window).load(function() {

Comment: @olegall, извините за тупой вопрос: а вы библиотеку jquery подключили?

Comment: всё я сделал, 2 плагина работают + мои скрипты

Comment: @olegall, выложите всю страницу с кодом на http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: выложил. сейчас работает, а у меня - нет
http://jsfiddle.net/eCdLt/1/

Comment: перед if вставьте вывод в console: console.log($('.class_link').text()); console.log("хатха"); и посмотрите что выводит.

Comment: Ну так все та же проблема с encoding. Я вот зашел по ссылке на код посмотреть. Все русские буквы - это ромбики.

Comment: Ну если скрипт делает запрос и по запросу получает этот текст, то проблема все еще в кодировке. На одной странице одна, на другой другая, поэтому ломается при переходе. Нужно все и вся привести к единому виду тогда и работать все будет.

Comment: что выдает console.log($('.class_link').text()); ?

Comment: если раскомментировать

в [http://jsfiddle.net/eCdLt/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/eCdLt/4/)

то выдает ошибку

>> **Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'nivoSlider'**

вы к fiddle тоже все библиотеки подключите

Comment: на сайте  строка в .class_link равна

> **йога-зарядкахатха-йогакласс терапиихатха-йогайога-flow**

Answer (score 1):

Я напишу ответ.

вместо того чтобы обращаться напрямую к $('.class_link') вам нужно обращаться к

```
this.$el;
```

примерно таким способом:

```
switch (this.$el.text()) {

    case "хатха-йога":
        this.title = 'Занятие состоит из статических, динамических и дыхательных упражнений, которые в совокупности оказывают положительное воздействие на центральную  нервную систему, улучшают кровообращение, укрепляют порно-двигательный аппарата и обеспечивают слаженную работу всех систем организма! Заниматься по системе хатха-йоги могут люди с любым уровнем подготовки!';
        break;

    case "йога-зарядка":
        this.title = 'Утренний комплекс хатха-йоги с элементами суставной гимнастики, направленный на повышение общего тонуса организма. Заменяет кофе!!!';
        break;

    case "перинатальная йога":
        this.title = 'Йога для женщин, находящихся на различных сроках беременности. Занятия в этот период помогут будущей маме облегчить дискомфорт, вызванный токсикозом, избавиться от болей в спине и ногах, укрепить мышцы абдоминальной области, и области малого таза, что обеспечит наиболее комфортные роды, специальные дыхательные упражнения помогут восстановить кислородный баланс, необходимый для правильного развития малыша. Практикуя йогу регулярно, женщина обретает внутреннее равновесие и способность справляться со стрессами современного мегаполиса)))';

}
```

ॐ

Comment: ॐ — в индуистской и ведийской традиции — сакральный звук, изначальная мантра. Часто интерпретируется как символ божественной троицы Брахмы, Вишну и Шивы, квинтэссенция Слова. В соответствии с ведийским наследием, считается, что звук ом был первым проявлением не явленного ещё Брахмана, давшим начало воспринимаемой Вселенной, произошедшей от вибрации, вызванной этим звуком.

Comment: @Олег Б , что вы хотели этим сказать ?

Comment: Вы закончили ваш ответ этим символом!

Comment: Да, я всего-лишь имел ввиду, что благодаря вселенскому просветлению я постиг суть проблемы, а так-же выражаю таким образом единение с вопрошающим и одновременно я высказал заверение в том, что  моё желание ему помочь искренне и я лично одобряю его деятельность в конкретном моменте времени.

Answer (score 0):

`$('.class_link').text()` - изначально не подразумевает единичное значение, классов на странице может быть много, поэтому вы получаете в ответе массив из объектов, даже если он и один там.

Вам нужно или перейти на id, или проверять значение через each.
Может даже сработает и такой вариант `$('.class_link')[0].text()`